# Use ReWriteEngine to redirect user profile page to a physical page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Good day,

I want to rewrite my user id URL to a physical page on my website, see URL structure below:

From:
http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/user.php?id=341

To:
http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/341

This is the .htaccess file code:

```
ReWriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^report.mark1([^/.]+)?$ /user.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I'm I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules file. Make sure your .htaccess file is present alongside with report.mark1 folder and your user.php is present inside report.mark1 folder.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /report.mark1/
##External redirect change of URL rules here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(report\.mark1)/user\.php\?id=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite to user.php rules here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)(\d+)/?$ /report.mark1/user.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thank you so much this works :) 

for some reason it only reads the page if I add .php manually to the URL:

from: http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/341
to: http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/341.php

Then the last question, let's say I want to redirect the URL
From: 
http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/user.php?id=341

To:
From: http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/client/home

How do I do this?

Sorry I've very new to this

Comment: @AnrichMark1, ok so you mean you want to make it work for URL `localhost:8888/report.mark1/341` too? and you are not hitting url `localhost:8888/report.mark1/341.php`  in browser?

Comment: so what happens when I go to http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/user.php?id=341 it redirects to http://localhost:8888/report.mark1/341 but then I get the following message: Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server. But if I add .PHP after the 341 the page content shows

Comment: so I need to add the .php extension manually in the browser before the content shows

Comment: @AnrichMark1, ok in my rules try changing last line to `RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)(\d+)/?$  /report.mark1/user.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]` once and let me know how it goes, I have put `/` before `report.mark1` try it out and let me know, cheers.

Comment: @AnrichMark1,your welcome, you can click on tick mark near to my answer to accept it. Accepting answer is a way to say thanks and it will help future users to see that this answer was helpful too.

Comment: Can I throw in a curveball? 
If I want the destination page to be: localhost:8888/report.mark1/client/home

So redirect: localhost:8888/report.mark1/user.php?id=341
to: localhost:8888/report.mark1/client/home

Comment: @AnrichMark1, this looks like a new question to me, so kindly open a new question for same, cheers. We can discuss it there .

Comment: I can only post in 90min, once I've posted I'll notify you here?
This is will be the title of the post:
I want to rewrite my user id URL to a physical page on my website

You are a legend

Comment: @AnrichMark1, ok np. So you are hitting link localhost:8888/report.mark1/client/home in browser? And you want to redirect it? Could you please explain it more. thank you.

Comment: no worries, I think let me post the question as a new one, cause there are more things I added in the new question, I don't mind waiting for 90min :)